# Syntax Error with subquery in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, subquery, stripe-payments

I have one table with all webhooks from Stripe. My challenge now is to match a customers id found in a charge.succeeded event with one event that contains her e-mail address, which would be an event called customer.created.

My attempt was to first select for the customer's id found in the charge.succeeded event and than ask in a sub query to find a customer.created event that matches the customers id, therefore retrieving her e-mail address.

Though I am not sure wether I am using the right syntax to do so or my attempt started with the wrong foot in general.

```
SELECT p.created_at as date
     , s.`name`
     , JSON_EXTRACT(p.payload, '$.data.object.amount') as amount
     , JSON_EXTRACT(p.payload, '$.data.object.application_fee_amount') as fee_amount
     , JSON_EXTRACT(p.payload, '$.data.object.id') as charge
     , p.event_type as type
     , JSON_EXTRACT(p.payload, '$.data.object.customer') AS cus_id_charge
    , cus_email
  FROM
( SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(pw.payload, '$.data.object.email') AS cus_email
   FROM payment_webhooks AS pw
   WHERE pw.event_type = "customer.created" 
          AND (JSON_EXTRACT(pw.payload, '$.data.object.id' = cus_id_charge)
) AS customer_created
            , payment_webhooks AS p
      LEFT 
      JOIN subsidiaries AS s 
        ON JSON_EXTRACT(p.payload, '$.account') = s.stripe_id 
     WHERE p.event_type IN("charge.succeeded","charge.failed") 
       AND NOT s.name = "Test Autohaus"
 ORDER 
    BY p.created_at;
```

Error Message: 
Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS customer_created, payment_webhooks AS p
LEFT JOIN subsidiaries AS s ON JSON_E' at line 6

Comment: You're missing a `)` in `JSON_EXTRACT(pw.payload, '$.data.object.id' = cus_id_charge`

Comment: You missed a parenthesis: `(JSON_EXTRACT(pw.payload, '$.data.object.id') = cus_id_charge)`

Comment: Ah thanks, that's it.